# How to change element name in C# xml serialize?

Tags: c#, xml

I am defined a simple class and serialized it:

```
    public class Test
    {
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }
```

I am serized this simple object,the code like this:

```
                Test test = new Test();
                test.Name = "a";                    
                TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\a.xml");
                XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test), "");
                s.Serialize(writer, test);
                writer.Close();
```

The ***a.xml*** result file like this:

```
<Test xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
  <Name>a</Name>
</Test>
```

That's no problem,but now i want my xml node content like this(***change the default element name(like: Test) to user define name,whatever the name is(like: job-scheduling-data)***):

```
<job-scheduling-data xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
  <Name>a</Name>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

What can i do to make it right? I don't want my class name like "**job-scheduling-data**".

Comment: You may want to use decorator attribute?`[XmlElement(Name="somename")]`

Comment: There's a whole section of MSDN devoted to XML Serialization, such as [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "job-scheduling-data")]
public class Test
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

you can check [this msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes,it works.Thank you.I have tried this way for so much times,but my another class is very complex and it has no effect.

Comment: what do you mean by complex? If you mean inheritance, if you check the msdn page you will see the related configuration related to derived types.